# What is the proper way to create a Hybrid Data structure of Ternary Search Trees

Tags: java

I am trying to create a class called HybridTST, where I can add multiple different TST's to a bigger data structure. 
I have tried creating an array of Ternary Search Trees to a letter in the alphabet and then when I want to go to a specific TST I can iterate through the alphabet to find the correct TST. I am not sure if that the outcome is what I want. Am I creating a this Hybrid TST incorrectly?

```
public class HybridTST<E> implements TrieInterface
{

private TST[] myHybridTST = new TST[54]; 
private String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.'";
private int position = 0;

private int size;

HybridTST()
{
    char[] alphabetArray = alphabet.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i<54; i++)
    {
        myHybridTST[i]= new TST(alphabetArray[i]);
    }
}

@Override
public Object get(String key) {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(key.charAt(i))) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException();
        }
    }


    position = 0;
    for(char c: alphabet.toCharArray())
    {
        if(key.charAt(0)==c)
        {
            break;
        }
        position++;
    }


    return myHybridTST[position].get(key);
}
```

Here is the TST get portion:

```
    public Object get(String key) {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException();
    }
    if (key == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if(key!="aren't")
            {


    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(key.charAt(i))) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException();
        }
    }
            }
    Node x = get(root, key, 0);
        if (x == null) return null;
        return x.val;

}

private Node get(Node x, String key, int d) {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException();
    }
    if (key.length() == 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("key must have length >= 1");
    if (x == null)
        return null;
    char c = key.charAt(d);

    if (c<x.c)
    {
        return get(x.left, key, d);
    }
    else if(c>x.c)
    {
        return get(x.right, key, d);
    }
    else if(d < key.length()-1)
    {
        return get(x.mid, key, d+1);
    }
    else
    {
        return x;
    }

}
```

Here is the test:

```
    public void test10()
    {
    HybridTST<Integer> t = new HybridTST<Integer>();
    t.put("A",new Integer(0));
    t.put("AB",new Integer(1));
    t.put("ABC",new Integer(2));
    assertEquals( new Integer(0), t.get("A") );
    assertEquals( new Integer(1), t.get("AB") );
    assertEquals( new Integer(2), t.get("ABC") );
    }
```

It its failing to get any items that I have put into the data structure.

My Hybrid TST PUT method:

```
    public void put(String key, Object val) {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new InvalidKeyException();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i <1; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(key.charAt(i))) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException();
        }


    }
    int count = 0;
    int position = 0;

    position = 0;
    for(char c: alphabet.toCharArray())
    {
        if(key.charAt(0)==c)
        {
            break;
        }
        position++;
    }




    size++;
    myHybridTST[position].put(key, val);



}
```

In my TST class,

```
    private static class Node {
    private char c; // character
    private Node left, mid, right; // left, middle, and right
                                    // subtries
    private Object val; // value associated with string
    public Node[] next;

    Node(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}


public TST(char c) {
    this.root = new Node(c);
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the get method. Are you sure the items are correctly put into each TST ?

Comment: I know, that's what I was thinking. My put method is implemented just like my get. I have added it towards the bottom. thank you.

Comment: How are you instantiating your TST's ? (the line i'm referring is `       myHybridTST[i]= new TST(alphabetArray[i]); ` )

Comment: I have added what I believe answers your question. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Is there any way you can paste the whole code somewhere as it could be easier ? (gist/pastebin/other)

Comment: Here is the HybridTST.java and here is the TST.java files.  I appreciate your help!  http://pastebin.com/LFnrck7A  http://pastebin.com/EwbCkapK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problem running your code, inserting and fetching values from the tree. However, it can be improved in some way:

- Remove unused attributes
- Use generics so you force the type of the elements you insert and fetch from the HybridTST and TST
- Indentation is sometimes off
- The code doesn't work as is (`Node doesn't have method visit`)
- Instead of getting the position of the first letter on the alphabet, create a helper method for that.
- Instead of calling `new Integer(i)`, use `Integer.valueOf(i)`
- From what I can see, your code contains the attribute of a 256-way trie plus the one for a ternary search tree, you should clean it